# Unexpected behavior in Laravel 5.3 installation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My Laravel project randomly shows ***connection refused exception***, but it was working before, so I type

```
php artisan config:cache
```

and the error disappear, but after that, it throws ***View not found exception*** I ran

```
php artisan config:cache
```

again without success. After that, I type

```
php artisan route:cache
php artisan route:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
composer dump-autoload
```

but the exception ***View not found*** still there, so I don`t know what else to do.

I use vagrant with Homestead 7.

NOTE: Yesterday I migrate my installation to a fresh one because the same problem, but today it appears again.

Comment: Can you give some more informations about your project?

Comment: what information do you need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel view not found exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913929/laravel-view-not-found-exception)

Comment: @DestinatioN i already see that post, no helped me, thanks.

Comment: make sure that dir `/storage` is writable

Comment: it is writable, thanks @skido

Comment: @AndresFelipe sometimes I have errors like these... because of different cached views owners and too strict file access permissions.

Comment: Are you certain the view you are trying to load is actually there?

Comment: i just deleted the files inside the folders in storage, so it has to re build them, but nothing, @user3158900 yes the view is there, it was working before.

Comment: @AndresFelipe Do you have this problem with all view scripts?

Comment: @skido, yes, i've return some random string and it appears, but when i use some view it throws the view not found error

Comment: @AndresFelipe
make sure that laravel loads correct config for views (run `dd(app('view')->getFinder());` in Controller where you have this error) and this view script can be found.

Comment: Guys thanks so much for the replays, i migrate again and the problem is gone, but later i will indagate more about this and come back to tell you how it goes, thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, after many attempts i ran

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

and the problem is now gone.