# Laravel View not found in Production

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, shared-hosting

I've deployed my laravel application to the shared hosting but it cant find the view. Any step that I forgot?

This is the url : [production site](http://vgo2.iopenwise.com/)

Comment: Can you check if you have `app.blade.php` inside your `resources/views` folder? If not, you might want to `return view('layouts.app')` instead.

Comment: @AdlanArifZakaria Ya. the file app.blade.php is available. Not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913929/laravel-view-not-found-exception). Please find the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914115/2427738) to solve your query

Comment: what is the location of your app.blade.php file? What are you returning from your controller?

Answer (score 0):

Go to resources folder
Go to view folder
check whether it has app.blade.php

Here, your error means, it cannot find the blade file in view folder. As you have mentioned return view("app"), this will try to find app.blade.php in view folder.

If still there is no success, try clearing cache
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear

Also go to config/view.php file and check your defined path for view files.

I hope this helps

Comment: Ya. the app.blade.php is available in view folder but it still doesn't work

Comment: ok then try this command

php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear

you view may be because of cache also

Comment: Hey got your issue, go to config/view.php, resources spelling is wrong there, correct it and check. 

you have written resourcrs @Jakz

Comment: Are you sure there is a type? I can't find it in config/view.php

Comment: @Jakzs go to config/view.php, (the "View Storage Paths" section)

'paths' => [ realpath(base_path('resources/views')) ],

Comment: for clearing cache, login with ssh, go inside laravel folder

run php artisan cache:clear and then run
php artisan view:clear

Comment: I've changed the config/view.php file but it still doesn't work. I've clear the cache too.

Comment: can you post your config file photo here once and also restart you server once then

Answer (score 0):

Could you try giving permissions to the storage folder.

`chmod -Rv 777 storage/` or `chown -Rv  :www-data storage/`

Sessions folder is not found in your storage directory maybe its not able to create it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and the solution was to change the file names to short names