# View [index] not found in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, view

my website run correctly at localhost but when i upload it on CPanel it makes a mistake and say me view index not found

> InvalidArgumentException View [index] not found.

this is my Route Code:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});
```

Also i executed these commands:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config: clear
php artisan view:clear
composer update
php artisan route:clear
```

but it have no response!!!!!

Comment: maybe it is because of routing. please show your code

Comment: Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('index');
    });

Comment: try using controller for rendering view it is standard,and check it

Comment: it didn't work ):

Comment: Did you put your view file in correct directory and name it correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel view not found exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913929/laravel-view-not-found-exception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it, i upload new project and it solved but i don't know what is the issue of last project. It's so weird

Answer (score 1):

What's your `resources/views` directory's permission? It should accessible by your web server.

Comment: all folders are 755 and all files are 644

Answer (score 0):

You should try : php artisan cache:clear

Answer (score 0):

If these commands work:

```
 php artisan config:cache or php artisan
 config:clear?
 named your view correctly with yourview.blade.php?
 placed the view correctly in the resources\views?
```

Maybe the problem is that your server is not setting up properly because the domain doesnt connected properly to your VPS. Contact the hosting provider.

Comment: this issue is for all of my views but when i return json or string instead of view it will work