# Error message after integrating my admin panel dashboard in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dashboard

This is error I get when I try to integrate my admin panel dashboard in laravel

```
View [layouts.adminLayouts.admin_header] not found. 
(View: D:\admin\resources\views\layouts\adminLayout\admin_design.blade.php) 
(View: D:\admin\resources\views\
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, describe what you want to achieve, what you did, and response you got.

Comment: go to your `views/layouts/adminLayouts/admin_header.blade.php` and verfiy this file exists.

Comment: If this answer has helped you, @mun-mak , don't hesitate to upvote. If it has resolved your problem, don't hesitate to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when Laravel doesn't find a view file in your application.

1. **Verify that the template needed exists**

As @omar-abdullah said, go to `views/layouts/adminLayouts/` and verify that `admin_header.blade.php` exists (it may also work if you have called it `admin_header.php`).

2. **Verify that the template has the correct permission**

Make sure it has the correct file permission (the web server should be able to read it!). That could happen on, for instance, linux machines.

Type `ll` and make sure the permissions, file owner and group is the same for this template and for others, and that the adminLayout folder has the same permisison than other similar folders.

3. **Cache error?**

If the problem persists, it might be a cache error.

Run the command under the project folder:

```
php artisan optimize --force
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
```

-

See [laravel view not found exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913929/laravel-view-not-found-exception)