# View emailrecrutamento not found when i upload my site in heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I have one application in heroku, this application make a function that sends one email, everything works on local php artisan serve, but when i upload to heroku i have this error:

> exception: "InvalidArgumentException" file:
>   "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php"
>   line: 137 message: "View [emailrecrutamento] not found."

my view is in resources/views/emailrecrutamento.blade and this is my function:

```
public function enviaEmailRerutamento(Request $request){

    $data = array(
        'id_usuario' => $request->id_usuario,
        'emailContato' => $request->emailContato,
        'mensagem' => $request->mensagem,
    );

    Mail::send('emailrecrutamento', $data, function ($message){
        $message->from('suporte@cademeupet.net', 'Nova solicitação de privilégios')->subject('Ação necessária no sistema Cade Meu pet');
        $message->to('renatim@hotmail.com.br');
    });

    return response()->json("Obrigado pela inscrição, entraremos em contato em breve", 201);
}
```

Comment: heroku does not read .env have you configured your config/mail.php ?

Comment: Surely you mean `resources/views/emailrecrutamento.blade.php` right?

Comment: @AhmedAboud Yes, i conffgure my mail.php: driver, host, port, from, encryption, username/password. The variable "sendmail" have this value: 'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs', and the markdown: " 'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
i'm missing something?

Comment: @miken32 yes, this is the path

Comment: i think you need a mail addon

Comment: https://elements.heroku.com/addons/categories/email-sms which one of these you are using ?

Comment: i'm not using a addon, i'm only using laravel. which addon i have to add to send email with laravel in heroku?

Comment: I'm not sure, but in Laravel function name should be same as file name. Please check Laravel Views documentation. Something wrong with "enviaEmailRerutamento"

Comment: @renaotpls2019 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913929/laravel-view-not-found-exception please check the second answer