# Laravel InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:

Tags: php, laravel

I want to open a Laravel project which I developed few years ago on my Xampp localhost. I copied the folder to Xampp/htdocs/myproject. I installed the composer and laravel too. When I open the project in browser I can't the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
View [index] not found.
```

I also tried to run the php artisan serve command but  it does not work. It gives error:

```
could not open input file: artisan
```

Comment: regarding PHP artisan: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193314/could-not-open-input-file-artisan

Comment: for the view not found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913929/laravel-view-not-found-exception

Answer (score 0):

It is better to clear the app cache after moving the project to other servers. Try these-

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

I hope it will help. :)