# view not found exception-laravel

Tags: php, laravel, exception, notifications, laravel-8

`View [cart] not found. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): View [cart] not found. at C:\\wamp\\www\\projects\\BBT\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\FileViewFinder.php:137)`

I've created a `notification` & tried to use the `cart.blade.php` as the mail template as below. But am getting the above error. i've already tried clearing cache by going through this link:  `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913929/laravel-view-not-found-exception`

```
namespace App\Notifications;
class CartExpiryNotification extends Notification
{
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->view('cart', ['cartTemplate' => 'cartTemplate']);
    }
}
```

**cart.blade.php**

```
{{$cartTemplate}}
```

`cart.blade.php` is existing in the path `C:\wamp\www\projects\BBT\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Notifications\resources\views\cart.blade.php` .

Comment: Views should be placed in the `/resources/views` folder, not in a `/vendor/...` folder

Comment: @brombeer ok.now i moved the `cart.blade.php` to the file location  `C:\wamp\www\projects\BBT\resources\views\vendor\notifications\cart.blade.php` .Still it shows same error

Comment: `view('cart' ...` expects the blade file to reside in the `/resources/views` folder - not any subfolder inside. Might want to read [Creating & Rendering Views](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#creating-and-rendering-views)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your views should be inside following root directory

```
your_project_name/app/resources/views/cart.blade.php
```